# Intermittent SoapClient I/O warning: failed to load external entity

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, fedex

I'm using the Fedex shipping API to create waybills. Intermittently I'm receiving the following error when
I send the API request:

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/user/public_html/includes/modules/vendor/jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/src/FedEx/_wsdl/UploadDocumentService_v11.wsdl" in /home/user/public_html/includes/modules/vendor/jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/src/FedEx/AbstractRequest.php on line 53

Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '/home/user/public_html/includes/modules/vendor/jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/src/FedEx/_wsdl/UploadDocumentService_v11.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "/home/user/public_html/includes/modules/vendor/jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/src/FedEx/_wsdl/UploadDocumentService_v11.wsdl" in /home/user/public_html/includes/modules/vendor/jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/src/FedEx/AbstractRequest.php on line 53
```

The strange this is it only happens on certain shipments. For example I'll have shipments A, B, C. Shipment A will ship fine, B will throw the error, C will ship fine, I'll go back to retry B and it will still fail. I'll keep trying it over and over again and then eventually it will go through (random amount of time later with no changes to the API request).

The other strange thing is I'm loading the WSDL locally, so there shouldn't be any issues loading it in. Googling around I found that most often this issue occurs when you're loading the WSDL from an external source.

When I initialize my SOAP client, I pass the static WSDL local path along with the following options:

```
$options = array(
            'cache_wsdl' => 0,
            'trace' => 1,
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
                  'ssl' => array(
                       'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true
                  )
            )));
```

Anyone have any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

It ended up having to do with a bug in PHP 5.6 and the Linux distribution we are using, combined with using the Soap Client. The issue has to do with race conditions and was solved by adding `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);` at the beginning of our application.